# how do I add my own css to laravel backpack

Tags: css, laravel-backpack

when I inspect the laravel page for css files, I see that one of the css files is http://localhost/packages/backpack/base/css/bundle.css?v=5.0.10@f0c0c45914c39a9083e19f0c5c3d10ef0e142565">

How do I add my own css to this laravel project which uses backpack?

Answer (score 1):

To add your own CSS to Laravel Backpack, create your own CSS file(s) then open up the base configuration file at /config/backpack/base.php and look for the styles[] and mix_styles[] and add the path to your CSS file(s) here, your file(s) will then be included on all Backpack generated pages.

If you add it to styles[] it will be included on all pages, if you add it to mix_styles[] make sure that Laravel Mix can find it as it will run through the mix() helper to include it with all Backpack views.